# Passing Javascript variable to href

Tags: javascript

I need to pass a variable containing the name of a picture contained in an array, this is how it looks like:

```
xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
// alert("step 1");
xhttp.open("GET","xml/emp2.xml",false);
} 
xhttp.send("");
xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;
var TestP = new Array();

TestP[n] = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[n].textContent;
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = url="pic/"+ TestP[n];
```

The images are in a folder called pic, and the name is obtained by storing it in img.src, and I want it to pass in the url. How to do this?

My HTML snippet :

```
<a href="pic/'img.src'" rel="shadowbox" onClick="OpenNewWindow(1,800, 600)">Part 1</a></li>
```

Comment: Isn't there a for-loop missing?

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand your question well but I think you want to change your anchor's href value.

If so you could simply use getElementById to retrieve your element and then set its href property.
Another option is to dynamically create your A tags using createElement and then set their href value like **myAtag.href='myurl'**

Comment: The name of the picture is stored in : img.src
Now in the href tag, i want the source to be pic/img.src , which means for example pic/1.jpg having "pic" a folder where the images are stored. so how can i do this?

Comment: There isnt such thing as href tag. What did you mean by 'source'. And ist this : 'myAtag.href=img.src' what you need? I still cant understand what are you asking about?

Comment: i appologise for not making myself clear.
i have an array full of pictures names, and i want the href to be equal dynamically to the value stored

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the anchor `href` to be the same as the image source? If so, first give it unique id:

```
<a id="MyImageLink" href="pic/'img.src'" rel="shadowbox" ....>
```

Then have such code:

```
var imageName = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[n].textContent;
TestP[n] = imageName;
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "pic/" + imageName;
var oLink = document.getElementById("MyImageLink");
oLink.href = "pic/" + imageName;
```

Comment: The name of the picture is stored in : img.src
Now in the href tag, i want the source to be pic/img.src , which means for example pic/1.jpg having "pic" a folder where the images are stored. so how can i do this?

Comment: What you mean "didn't work"? What **did** happen? Do you get any errors?

Comment: the document didn't read the variable, he didn't knw the meaning of the href. my variable is stored in the head section in javascript, i just want to pass it in the href, that's just what i want to do what's the syntax

Comment: What you say makes no sense and conflicts with your code which seems to read the image name from XML file, not from head section or anything. Please revise your question, post more code and explain what exactly is going on.