# Passing variable from javascript to href

Tags: javascript

I have a variable in javascript that contains the directory of an image.
I want to pass it to an href 
how to do this?

```
    function OpenNewWindow(n, width, height)
    {
          if( navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
            xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            xhttp.open("GET","http://www.multimediaprof.com/test/emp2.xml",false); 
            }
        else if(navigator.appName == "Netscape"){

        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        // alert("step 1");
        xhttp.open("GET","xml/emp2.xml",false);
        } 
        xhttp.send("");
        xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML;

var imageName = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes[n].textContent;
TestP[n] = imageName;
alert(TestP[n]);
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = "pic/" + imageName;
alert(img.src);
return img.src;

<li><a href="javascript:OpenNewWindow(1,000,000);alert('clicked!');" rel="shadowbox" ">Part 0</a></li>
```

The variable img.src contains the path, and i want to  pass it to the href

Comment: Please provide some of your code.

Comment: Increase your accept to green level

Comment: What was wrong as you [asked it the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804790/passing-javascript-variable-to-href)?

Comment: i still dunno how simply can i do it :S no one provided me with the right info

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's really not needed since you can simply trigger the `window.location = 'http://whatever...';` and your page will redirect there. But if you want to pass it, just get the element: `var a = document.getElementById('yourelementid');` then assign your var to it: `a.setAttribute('href',yourvariable);` ..

Comment: Yes. I don't want to sound mean but your code looks like you copy-pasted something without knowing what it means, starting from the syntax errors like not even closing the function, etc. The only thing I recommend is to learn some of the $.ajax and jQuery in general from http://jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

if you have a this kind of element this is what you need to do.

```
<a id="sample">My href</a>

var url = 'your url';
```

You can assign the variable as follows.

```
$('#sample').attr('href',url);
```

or else

```
$('#sample').attr('href') = url;
```

I have posted this answer according you your initial question which did not had this much of  clarification.

Comment: can u adjust your answer so that it will be compatible with my code? i thank you in advance